# Convert calendar month numbers to financial month name

Tags: r

name of data.frame is `df`

```
   `Level 4 AN` `Accounting Year` Month ActualCost

 1          Pay              2013     1   48950305
 2          Pay              2013     2   82147447
 3          Pay              2013     3   64976400
```

I want to have this:

```
1          Pay              2013     April   48950305
2          Pay              2013     May   82147447
3          Pay              2013     June   64976400
```

Please note that I want to replace `1`  with `April` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = 1:12
# OR you could do
#i = df$Month
month.name[ifelse(i == 9, 12, (i + 3) %% 12)]
# [1] "April"     "May"       "June"      "July"      "August"    "September"
# [7] "October"   "November"  "December"  "January"   "February"  "March"
```

Comment: how do I add this to my df file?

Comment: new data frame dff<-df$Month = month.name[ifelse(df$Month == 9, 12, (df$Month + 3) %% 12)]......I am lost a bit.the code to get the final output

Answer (score 3):

R has a couple of stored character vectors including month.name.

```
 month.name[1:4]
 [1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"
```

Using this, create financial month vector like this:

```
finMonth <- month.name[c(4:12, 1:3)]
finMont[1:4]
[1] "April" "May"   "June"  "July"
```

Then, use indexing to assign the replacement column.

```
dat$month <- finMonth[dat$month]
```

Comment: Hi I have a problem here. when I get to March it should be 2014 March but I am having 2013 March... my financial year is  April 2013 to March 2014

Comment: Then your data is different from the above example that you provided as this method does not touch the year. I suggest that you ask a *new* question, linking to this question, with an example dataset that illustrates the additional complication.